# Combining Multiple Windows

Tags: c++, winapi, sfml

How can we combine many windows client area in one.

I have 2 different windows and i want to combine it in to one.

The first window is made in open cv    and the second one has all the interface options
(the second window is designed in sfml)

the third window(in which i want other windows to combine) is designed in win32 api

is there any way to do this?

Comment: Is there a way? probably...but it'll be easier to rewrite the whole GUI at this point.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can merge them is to have one top-level parent window and have separate child windows that host the OpenCV and SFML contents.

However, I suspect that OpenCV (and possibly SFML) expects a top-level window; you'll have to experiment to be sure.

A quick search of the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/) shows that there's no standard OpenCV function that takes a (provided) HWND, so you'll have to dig into the OpenCV internals (most likely `namedWindow`) and create your own function that creates a child window from a given HWND parent.

[SFML](http://sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.1/group__window.php) appears to have the same restriction; in this case, since SFML appears to be based on OpenGL, this may not be possible at all, as OpenGL doesn't like being in a child window.

An alternate approach is to set the window styles on the OpenCV and SFML windows to be borderless, and have the Win32 window move/size the other windows when the Win32 window moves.  This requires a lot of attention to detail to minimize "tearing", but it can be done.  (For example, Windows Media Player does this for its control window.)